# Node.js - An error occurred during import third party library

Tags: node.js, es6-modules

Guys I am still new to `Node.js` and facing a problem during importing a third-party module. The module name is [@azure/storage-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/storage-blob) and my `package.json` file is using `"type": "module"` setting.

When I try to import this module with the following syntax. I am getting an error.

```
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";

SyntaxError: The requested module '@azure/storage-blob' does not provide an export named 'BlobServiceClient'
    at ModuleJob._instantiate (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:92:21)
    at async ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:107:20)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:179:24)
```

But with this setting, this project is working fine on my other machine and I still don't understand it.

When I use this syntax instead of directly import the error goes away.

```
import AzureStorageBlob from "@azure/storage-blob";
const { BlobServiceClient } = AzureStorageBlob;
```

Could you please help me to understand this issue?

Comment: Do not mix _destructuring_ with module _import_ syntax. Import statement that produces an error is for importing a _named_ export which, as the error message states, is not provided by the `@azure/storage-blob` package. Second import statement that works fine is for importing _default_ exports and that is what `@azure/storage-blob` apparently provides. Once you have imported the default export, you can destructure it if it's an object.

Comment: @Yousaf Thanks for the reply, But on my other machine this syntax is working fine
`import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob"`, I got your point.

Comment: @Yousaf can you reply?

Comment: Maybe you are using a different version of `@azure/storage-blob` on the other machine?! Unless there is a named export, `import { BlobServiceClient  } from "..."` shouldn't work

Comment: What do you mean by "*But with this setting*"? The `type: module`? Are you saying it works without that?

Comment: What node version is installed on both machines? Are you using a transpiler?